Приветственный экран при успешном входе в рабочий стол Linux
Я хочу настроить сообщение при входе в систему (на рабочем столе) для Linux. Оно должно выглядеть как приветствие «Hello» на Mac при первом запуске. Да, это должно быть решение с графическим интерфейсом, а не сообщение в терминале и не просто уведомление на рабочем столе. Полноценная страница входа, как на Mac. Кроме того, оно должно появляться после успешного входа в систему (с графическим интерфейсом). Есть идеи, как это сделать?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

При входе в систему (рабочий стол), запрашивается пароль. Пользователь его вводит и успешно входит в систему. Я хочу сделать следующее. После успешного входа и перед открытием рабочего стола пользователю показывается приветственная надпись на весь экран, например, "Добро пожаловать". А после, уже открывался рабочий стол.

https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html ?

Lightdm -> [SeatDefaults] -> session-wrapper и/или greeter-wrapper вам в помощь. Ну а в чем вы там захотите организовать само приветствие... зависит в первую очередь от ваших хотелок и дистрибутива (например в виде уведомления, диалогового окна, алерта и чего угодно).
